Datadog to filter out endpoints by low counts
I am trying to find if there is a way to a minimum count to a specific endpoint before it alerts.
The issue is I have an alert which rolls up different endpoints and checks they are under a certain time threshold of two and a half seconds, over a thirty minute timeframe.
However, there are infrequent endpoints which get hit and require a cold start. Some of these endpoints may only get hit once in that thirty minute time span, and if they take too long they will alert.
The query is,
percentile(last_30m):p90:trace.netty.request{env:prod} by {resource.name} > 2.5
Is there a way I can hard code to say require at least 10 hits to that endpoint in the five minute threshold before tripping the alert?
Asking AI it tells me I can use an AND with,
count(last_30m):trace.netty.request{env:prod} by {resource_name} > 10
However, the Datadog GUI doesn't allow this pure query language without requiring selecting a bunch of GUI items.
Is there some way to enter the raw query, or how to use the GUI to set this up?

To set a minimum count threshold in Datadog for an alert, ensuring the alert only triggers if an endpoint is hit a certain number of times within a specified timeframe, you can modify the approach using Datadog’s alert settings, though the GUI doesn’t support raw query combinations as you might expect from traditional SQL-like queries.
Here’s how you can structure this through Datadog’s GUI to achieve the goal:
Steps to Set Up a Combined Alert with Count and Response Time Conditions:

Create a Composite Monitor: Datadog’s composite monitors let you create a logical "AND" across multiple monitors. This approach allows you to set one monitor to check the p90 response time and another monitor to check the count of requests for an endpoint, combining them to only trigger when both conditions are met.

Set Up Two Separate Monitors:

First Monitor (Response Time): Create a monitor for the response time condition, similar to what you already have:
percentile(last_30m):p90:trace.netty.request{env:prod} by {resource.name} > 2.5

This will monitor the response time for each endpoint over the last 30 minutes.

Second Monitor (Request Count): Create a monitor to track the count of requests for each endpoint:
count(last_30m):trace.netty.request{env:prod} by {resource.name} > 10

This ensures that only endpoints with at least 10 hits in the last 30 minutes will be considered for alerting.



Combine with a Composite Monitor:

Go to the Monitors section in Datadog.
Create a new Composite Monitor.
Select both monitors (response time and request count) created above and combine them using the AND condition.



This way, the composite monitor will only trigger an alert if:

The p90 response time of the endpoint exceeds 2.5 seconds, and
The count of requests to that endpoint is greater than 10 within the specified timeframe.

Additional Notes:

Using the GUI: Unfortunately, Datadog doesn’t allow raw query entry to create complex conditions directly. Using composite monitors is the closest solution, as it lets you combine simple monitors.
Alerts and Thresholds: Remember to adjust the timeframe of each monitor (e.g., last 30 minutes) to match your monitoring needs.

By setting up these monitors as described, your alert will only trigger for endpoints that are both slow and have a minimum level of traffic, reducing false positives from cold starts on infrequent endpoints.
